# I found a Ukranian spammer and have the exact query, IP and access time. What next?

Tags: security, log-files, spam

Before I turned on comment moderation, these guys would leave comments meant to steal my Google juice (by getting an inbound link). I can still see them visit... the question is

- what should I do next?
- Is there any way to know whether an entire ISP is spammer friendly or legit?
- Does Google Security want to know this info?

Currently I log what I know in my about page like this:

> 94.45.49.190 of the UKRAINE banned for [INTENT TO SPAM](http://www.google.com.ua/search?hl=ru&q=inurl:items++++%22post+a+comment%22)  on 2010 0114 at 04:41:11 AM PST

**EDIT**

Sorry for the delayed response.

Of course I know what whois is. I was prevented from using more than one limk as I was a complete n00b here. I reject the notion that "toasters" are the answer to the problem. (Zittrain says we would never reboot a fridge, and all computers should be more like toasters)

I can see this dude coming from the UKRAINE looking for a place to COMMENT using a special GOOGLE SEARCH: is this the best the ServerFault community can do?

If so, I have my answer: which is DON'T BOTHER ASKING HERE. It seems like the SquareSpace engineers are on top of it, and I have figured out the way around the gatekeeper there. So, this isn't that critical -- merely disappointing. I already logged the issue where everyone can find it, and made some suggestions.

Of course I'm not thinking of doing this for every IP... but I already started moderating comments, so in a way I'm already punishing innocent people because of these spammers. I can still see him/them visit though, and I'm surprised that there are no ideas for how to send a strong deterrent message to a spammer who's on my site in a comment or email form.

Come on, security people, you can do better than that.. Can't you?

Comment: @reechard: I moved your "update" here as edit, even though I don't exactly understand your point. If you have a comment or question about the community, please ask a question on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

it's par for the course when hosting anything on the internet. most comment spam/mail spam/really annoying ongoing ssh connection attempts etc. are pushed through botnets or proxied, so I really wouldn't worry about it.

if you spent time chasing every IP address you found trying to do something illicit, you wouldn't have time left for anything else...

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake. I asked this as a last resort. Of course I'm painfully aware of everything you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to report the ip address to the owner of the netblock, which you can find by doing a whois lookup on the ip address.

http://ws.arin.net/whois/

Comment: Is the entire netblock spammer-friendly? UKRAINE.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but the owner of the netblock has the responsibility and the authority to block any traffic from any ip address in the netblock.